# Does MapKit include bus route?

Tags: ios8, mapkit

I'm wondering does MapKit include bus route? When I create a new project with MapKit framework, I can choose routing with bus, or even ferry. But MKDirectionsTransportType only has three types, which are automobile, walk and any. 
Do I have to use Google API to get that feature? 
Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapKit doesn't offer this right now. You might be able to get what you are after by setting up your own [GraphServer](http://graphserver.github.io/graphserver/).